# How to deal with transform: translateY behavior

Tags: css, hover, transform

I have a problem with a `<div>` element which represents a card. On hover it is supposed to be traslated 20px up. Here's the code for it(I also included the animation if it is the case):

```
@keyframes Appear {
        from {
            transform: translateY(2em);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
            transform: translateY(0);
            opacity: 1;
        }
}

div {
    width: 32%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 calc(4% / 4) 20px;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    animation: Appear 0.4s ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
}
div:hover {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

The problem is that when I hover the `<div>` from under the element, it first is translated up but then starts trembling at the point of my cursor. This is just a visual defect, but is there a way to avoid this behavior somehow?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: wrap it in an element and trigger the translate when the parent is hovered. https://jsfiddle.net/tbem9nup/

Answer (score 0):

If you hover the bottom edge, it'll move up, your cursor will not hover it any more, so it'll move back down to be under your cursor, be hovered, and so on… You can counter this with a pseudo-element that'll fill that gap and keep the hover state active.

```css
.card-wrap {
    width: 32%;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 calc(4% / 4) 20px;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    
    position: relative; /* To contain the pseudo */
    overflow: visible; /* To allow the pseudo to overflow */
    
    background: red; /* For demo purposes */
}
.card-wrap:hover {
    transform: translateY(-20px);
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.card-wrap::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: inherit;
  background: blue; /* For demo purposes */
}

.card-wrap:hover::after {
  height: 20px;
}

.card { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-wrap"><div class="card"></div></div>
```

As you can see I had to change the `overflow: hidden` to achieve this. To counter this, a new element had to be introduced to re-apply `overflow: hidden`.

There are other ways to achieve this, hopefully this puts you on the right track.